# Does a snapped in half lug nut stud need to be replaced if a nut still goes on?

Tags: lug-nut

I snapped one of the lug nut studs on the front wheel hub on my 2003 Honda Civic in half when trying to get the nut off, but there was enough of the stud left that I bought a new nut and put it on. Because it's on a front hub, the replacement is going to be expensive since the hub has to be taken apart. Do I need to get the stud replaced, or is it fine to use it like this?

Comment: What kind of vehicle is this on? Is it a rotor or drum brake? Specifics, please. Many vehicles DO NOT need to be taken apart to replace a stud. Engineers sometimes get thing right and make it so you don't have to re-invent the wheel (pun intended) to fix things. As for your question, you could put it on there temporarily, but I'd replace the stud as soon as possible.

Comment: @Paulster2 It's a rotor brake. Apparently to replace the stud, the hub has to be removed, pressed apart to swap the stud, then pressed back together.

Comment: What type of vehicle is it, though? Is the rotor and hub one piece? Most are not ... if not, you should be able to pull the rotor (pull the caliper first), punch the broke stud out, replace it with new by drawing it through the hub with a stud nut (on the backside if a pass through design) or with a nut of the correct size putting some washers between the nut and the hub. It's really not that hard.

Comment: Oh, snap, just realized you put the vehicle into the body, lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this good video of how to do it without removing the hub/knuckle assembly from the vehicle. This is definitely one of those vehicles which engineers did not plan very well. [Here's the video on YouTube](http://youtu.be/a1w5nktjGJU). In case it is ever removed, here are the steps involved (follow safety protocols):

- Remove the tire, brake caliper, caliper bracket, and rotor.
- Clock the hub so the broken/stripped stud is positioned where the caliper would be
- With a hammer, punch the broken/stripped stud until loose
- Take a hacksaw or sawzall and cut the back side of the stud off
- Take the new stud and create a flat spot on the head using a grinder or file, being careful not to mess with the splines on the stud
- Clean the area behind where the stud will slip into the hub (you may also need to bend the rotor shield slightly)
- Slide the stud in from behind the hub, placing the flat spot on the head towards the knuckle assembly (further adjustments to the area may be needed, apply as necessary)
- Ensure the splines on the stud match up with the splines on the hub
- As suggested in the comments take a few washers (or a large nut) and a stud and draw the stud into the hub
- Reassemble the brakes and tire

I have no clue why designers/engineers don't make little things like this easy. If you take everything apart (hub) to replace the stud, you'd also need to put a new wheel bearing in there, because it would be destroyed in the process. As pointed out, there is a way to do this, just not as easy as was originally suggested.